# 'in the privacy of his kitchen.' what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, idioms

I am trying to translate some fanfics to Korean. Anyway, I can't understand the meaning of the sentence.

**Looking Will in the eyes gives Hannibal a tranquility that he usually only knows in the privacy of his kitchen.**

It is entire sentence. I tried to google like this; 'know in', 'in the privacy of one's kitchen', 'in the privacy of one's own', but nothing came.
What does it mean, is it a kind of idiom, or can I just translate it literally?

Comment: try googling: in the privacy of one's home. Anywhere in one's own house is usually private....

Answer (score 1):

It means that Hannibal's act of looking into Will's eyes makes Hannibal as tranquil as he feels when he is in the privacy of his own kitchen. This a correct but somewhat rare usage of **know** to mean **feel**.

Answer (score 1):

The standard idiom would use "in the privacy of one's own home" to mean a safe space, but there is a meaning specific to the character Hannibal (Lecter). He is a gourmand who enjoys cooking with his victims' flesh.  So as a lover of food, the kitchen holds a special place, privacy is required for his preparations, and he derives a perverse tranquility from preparing human flesh.  Looking at Will (Graham) gives Lecter the same feeling as when he's serving up a dinner guest.

...Unless you mean a different Will and Hannibal.

Answer (score 0):

"Know", in this instance, is referring to "tranquility", and it means "has experienced" or "is familiar with".

For some reason, Hannibal experiences remarkable tranquility in his kitchen (from what can only be guessed because I have no context). When he(?) (Hannibal) looks Will in the eyes, he(?) experiences that same tranquility.